# Wireless Communication Between Multiple Raspberry Pi's

Tags: wireless, wireless-adapter

I have a project I am working on that requires the following setup. There will be one "main" Raspberry Pi and 3 "secondary" Raspberry Pis. Each of the secondary ones need to be able to communicate back and forth wirelessly with the main one. What is the best way to do this?

I'm hoping for the main Pi to still be able to connect to the internet, so I picked up a wireless usb dongle. Ideally the built in wifi card in the Pi would connect it to the internet, and the usb dongle would open up a new wireless network for the secondary Pi's to connect to and pass data.

I tried following [this](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/) tutorial, but I don't think it's doing quite what I need.

I'm pretty new to Raspberry Pi's and Network stuff, so any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to the satellite RPis to get infer from the "main" pi or do you want them to send data to the main pi?

Comment: It needs to be both ways, information to and from the main pi and each of the satellite ones

Comment: Ah, your tutorial is WiFI. You can also do RF 2.G or 433MHz. I am using 433Mhz RF12, with master Rpi 4B and 10 slave Pico's. 4B can broadcast to multlple, say 10+ picos on the same one channel out of the many many 433Mhz sub channels. All little pico's can talk to each other or broadcast in half duplex.  For 2.4GHz, you can use cheapy BLE or nRF24L01+ serial/UART adaptor modules (yes, also smart phone interface, but only one to one, no broadcast stuff.

Comment: Send this query to Dr. Google's search engine: "learn MQTT". That will give you http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt/ which explains one of the easiest ways to send messages between Raspberries using the "internet of things protocol".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a router - implied by "main Pi to still be able to connect to the internet" do NOTHING!

The Pi will be able to communicate with each other through the router.

If you desperately need to communicate directly you need an Ad-hoc network.

Comment: Ah, so simple, wish I had asked before trying to figure things out myself. thank you so much!